# Select in Golang

Tags: sql-server, go

I want to connect a `MSSQL` database, in python I get connecting to this database but in `Go` I can not.

When I exec this code I receive this error:

> 2017/08/04 12:25:39 Select failed:Login error: EOF

why?

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
)

var (
    debug         = flag.Bool("debug", false, "enable debugging")
    password      = flag.String("password", "********", "the database password")
    port     *int = flag.Int("port", 1433, "the database port")
    server        = flag.String("server", "sql2008v\\2k8", "the database server")
    user          = flag.String("user", "usuario", "the database user")
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    if *debug {
        fmt.Printf(" password:%s\n", *password)
        fmt.Printf(" port:%d\n", *port)
        fmt.Printf(" server:%s\n", *server)
        fmt.Printf(" user:%s\n", *user)
    }

    connString := fmt.Sprintf("server=%s;user id=%s;password=%s;port=%d", *server, *user, *password, *port)
    if *debug {
        fmt.Printf(" connString:%s\n", connString)
    }
    conn, err := sql.Open("mssql", connString)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Open connection failed:", err.Error())
    }

    defer conn.Close()

    rows, err := conn.Query("SELECT TOP (1000) *  FROM [jiradb].[jiraschema].[jiraissue]")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Select failed:", err.Error())
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    fmt.Printf("bye\n")
}
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL (as mentioned in your question) or SQL server, as mentioned in your tag and your code?

Comment: As stated in the error, you're facing authentication issue. Check the library documentation for connection string and resolve your login issue. Then your query would work.

Comment: The user and password are ok, because when I use python the connection is ok. I don't understand because in go don't work. When I connect with sql.Open there isn't error. The error is in conn.Query.

Comment: One thing that you shouldn't assume is that just because you've done it one way with one language is that its going to work the same way with another language.  Forgot about how it works in python and debug why it doesn't work in Go. Also check that your server is running.